# How do I access an inner class constructor from a derived class?

Tags: java, constructor

For the below `Ocean` class,

```
public class Ocean {

    /**
     * Define any variables associated with an Ocean object here. These
     * variables MUST be private.
     */
    // width of an Ocean
    private final int width;
    // height of an Ocean
    private final int height;

    class Critter {

        /**
         * Defines a location of a Critter in an Ocean.
         */
        Point location;

        public Critter(int x, int y) {
            location = new Point(x,y);
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }
    }

    private Critter[][] oceanMatrix;
}
```

I would like to access constructor `Critter` in above class from below class `Shark` constructor.

```
class Shark extends Ocean implements Behaviour {

    public Shark(int x, int y, int hungerLevel) {
        super(x,y);
    }
}
```

How do I access `Critter` class constructor from `Shark` class constructor?

Comment: A shark is an ocean?

Comment: @ChrisMartin +1 My intention was to actually extend Ocean.Critter, which i did not know until i saw the below answer and right name for inner class `Critter` is `Position`.

Comment: "right name for inner class Critter is Position". I don't think it is. Extending a class implies an "is a" relationship. If `class Shark extends Position`, that implies that a Shark "is a" Position. But it isn't. It *has* a position, so you might use a Position class as a field of Shark, but if you want Shark to extend something, the right class is Critter.

Comment: @Boann if you see this [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68481/does-this-simulation-follow-abstraction-and-encapsulation), the design was as you said in `Critter` class. but based on toto2 comments, started changing the design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you should extend `Critter`instead of Ocean:

```
class Shark extends Ocean.Critter implements Behaviour{
...
    public Shark(int x, int y, int hungerLevel){
        super(x,y);

    }
...
}
```

For this to work, Critter needs to be a static inner class. I don't know how much of this design is yours, but inner classes should be limited to classes that are strongly dependent on each other, this isn't the case here. If you can, take Critter out of Ocean.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that Critter should not be a inner class. Seems like the author might be confusing Inner classes in classes for classes in packages.

Comment: If needed, it is possible to make it work if Critter is a non-static inner class using an obscure syntax called [qualified superclass constructor invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e14226). E.g., `class Shark extends Ocean.Critter { Shark(Ocean ocean, int x, int y) { ocean.super(x, y); } }`.

Comment: If i rename `Critter` class as `Position`, Do you think it make sense to inherit inner class `Position` to `Shark`. Why one would need to think that inner class should be limited to outer class only?

Comment: Why would i take `Position` class out of ocean, when it is relvant to place within Ocean?

Comment: A Critter being placed in an Ocean is sufficiently expressed in having the `Critter[][] oceanMatrix`field. If Critter is an inner class of Ocean it has access to private fields of Ocean, which leads to a high [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_\(computer_programming\)) of the classes.

Comment: Regarding the position class, a rule of thumb when extracting a superclass is 1st: the extracted class has a non-trivial functionality and 2nd: the extracted class is to be extended by another class that is not Critter

Answer (score 3):

As long as `Shark` is in the same package as `Ocean`, AND you add the `static` modifier to `Critter`'s class declaration, you should be able to access `Critter` with `new Ocean.Critter()`

Comment: yes it makes more sense to declare `Critter` as static member in `Ocean` and no need to inherit `Ocean.Critter` in `Shark`. But from syntax point of view, if we inherit, `Ocean.Critter` to `Shark` class, then i get error on using super(x, y), why is that?